# how to automate the build system where it needs sudo privileges in Makefile without typing password

Tags: linux, jenkins, makefile, sudo

I've simple makefile target, that fetch the tar file, unpack it in `/opt` dir in Linux. In order to move files and unpack at `/opt` dir I need `sudo` privileges.

my makefile target,

```
TOOLCHAIN:=/opt/toolchains
bake-prep:
    @if [ ! -d $(TOOLCHAIN) ]; \
        then echo "Installing the ARM toolchain at /opt dir"; \
        mkdir -p $(TOOLCHAIN); \
        cp -r $(TOOLCHAIN_GIT)/. $(TOOLCHAIN) && echo "Copied the toolchain to host"; \
        echo "Unpacking the toolchain.."; \
        tar -xzf $(TOOLCHAIN)/$(TOOLCHAIN_ARCHIVE) -C $(TOOLCHAIN); \
        cd -; \
    else \
        echo "Toolchain is already installed"; \
    fi
```

I'm fine to use the target like `sudo bake-prep` in my host and I can type the password.

I want to run this in Jenkins. I don't want the build to stuck at `sudo` enter the password. Is it possible to make Jenkins have root privileges or is it possible to do something in `makefile`?

Comment: configure sudo to run a particular command (by a particular user) without asking a password. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/168461/how-do-i-sudo-without-having-to-enter-my-password and [man sudoers](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.14/sudoers.man.html)

Comment: If you could write a makefile that was able to run a `sudo` command without a password, it would defeat the purpose of the password (as any hacker/virus could write its own makefile and then run it).   You either need to run the makefile with `su` privalges, or do as @user3159253 suggested -- update the system to allow certain commands without passwords.  Note that you might be opening up a security hole if you do this though (specifically, someone could replace your compiler with malware, and it would activate next time _any_ user ran it)

Comment: Alternatively you can set write access to the /opt-folder in order to be writable by your user

Comment: I tried that didn't benefit me. In order to use `chown` utility to change privileges, I need to use `sudo` as well there.  /opt dir needs `sudo` access to any operation.

Comment: What @alex meant was you would have to run the `sudo chown` outside of the makefile, to add the particular user.  Then when that user ran make, it would have access to the directories from that point forward.

Comment: One can setup sudo to run a specific command by _a specific user_ or a group of users. So if one needs to run a privileged operation by a given user, it's possible to choose whether the user should authenticate herself with password, or it's a passwordless robot, or whatever else.